# Show children of custom taxonomy terms

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have the WP Jb manager plugin which I believe is just a custom post type for jobs. I have enabled categories created some categories.

I need to just show the children of each category instead of the whole list of categories.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'job_listing_category', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
 echo "<ul>";
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";

 }
 echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Which outputs a list of all categories (parent and children) as so:

- **Office**
- Warehouse
- Manufacturing
- **Industrial**
- **Construction**
- Building Services Engineers

The parent categories are the bold ones: Office, Industrial and Construction. I want to take one of them and display the children of that category only.

For example: `get_category('industrial', 'children_of')` (I know that's not the correct syntax), so it would result in showing the children only of the industrial category:

- Warehouse
- Manufacturing

I can't seem to find a way to do this - Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do this by using the following code:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'job_listing_category', 'parent=59' );
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
 echo "<ul>";
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";

 }
 echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the parent categories and then construct a list for each subcategory like so:

```
<?php
$taxonomies = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent' => 0,
));

if (!empty($taxonomies)):
    foreach ($taxonomies as $parent) {
        $output = '<ul>';
        $children = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
            'parent' => $parent->term_id,
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ));
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $output .= '<li>' . esc_html($child->name) . '</li>';
        }
        $output = '</ul>';
    }
    echo $output;
endif;
```

Note that the code wasnt tested. Find more info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Comment: Thanks so much for this - however it doesn't seem to output anything. I'm not sure if it matters but this code is for a homepage... I removed the commas from the end of the last items in the arrays (I thought they didn't need to be there, but still nothing I'm afraid